# Is It right way to create side collapsible panel navigation in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, navigation, panel

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function() {
            var mainView = new Ext.panel.Panel({
            xtype: 'panel',
            //title: 'Container',
            layout: 'border',
            itemId: 'bigContainer',
            height: '100vh',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                //title: 'Left Panel',
                itemId: 'menuLeftPanel',
                region: 'west',
                scrollable: true,
                //width: 300,
                //height: 900,
                dockedItems:
                [{
                    xtype: 'tabpanel',
                    collapseMode: 'header',
                    //animCollapse: 200,
                    dock: 'left',
                    id: 'moduleTas',
                    itemId: 'moduleTabs',
                    width: 400,
                    collapsible: true,
                    headerPosition: 'left',
                    hideCollapseTool: true,
                    //activeTab: 0,
                    tabBarHeaderPosition: 0,
                    tabRotation: 0,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        scrollable: 'y',
                        tabConfig: {
                            xtype: 'tab',
                            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home',
                            tooltip: "Home",
                            listeners:
                            {
                                click: function(btn, e, eOpts)
                                {
                                    var tab = Ext.getCmp('moduleTas');
                                    tab.toggleCollapse();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    ]
                },
                ]
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha provides an "Admin Dashboard" example application when you download the framework, that implements collapsible side navigation.  All the source code for the below layout (and every component found in the kitchen sink) can be found in the framework download.

[Admin Dashboard](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard)

[Admin Dashboard Source Code](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/extjs/tree/master/templates/admin-dashboard)

This isn't something you should be recreating yourself (defeats the point of using a framework like Extjs)